# Why we assigned the already allocated array to a new pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I'm dealing with malloc and i saw that code snippet. But I confused with that why we assign the already allocated array(buffer) to a new pointer(d). Could not we just check the buffer variable in if statement whether it has an adress or not ? Can anyone explain that pls ?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int *ft_range(int min, int max)
{
    int     range;
    int     index;
    int     *buffer;
    int     *d;

    if (min >= max)
        return (0);
    range = max - min;
    d = (buffer = malloc(range * sizeof(int))); <---------------HERE
    if (!d)
        return (0);
    index = 0;
    while (index < range)
    {
        buffer[index] = min + index;
        index++;
    }
    return (buffer);
}
```

Thanks in advance .

Comment: That is for absolutely no reason. The following check `if (!d)` can also be done with `buffer` instaed

Comment: @Gerhardh thank you so much. Another question is that Can i test the situation that malloc returned a NULL somehow ?

Comment: Yes, `if (!d)` is doing this. Any value that is not `0` is treated as `TRUE` and `!` is logical NOT operator. That means, `(!d)` is same as `(d == NULL)`

Comment: For clarification, `NULL` is just an alias for `0`.

Comment: `NULL` is *not* (necessarily) an alias for `0`.  It is often defined as `(void *) 0`, instead, which is not semantically equivalent to `0`, even though both can be used as null-pointer constants.

Comment: It is more relevant to say that null pointers evaluate to false in boolean context, and non-null pointers to true.  In particular, that means that `if (!d)` in the code presenting is testing whether `d`'s value is a null pointer.  This is not directly related to the fact that integer 0 evaluates to false in boolean context, and integer nonzero to true.